# How to calculate SL and TP in PineScript 5, why doesn't my code work?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Why can't I find a way to set an SL and TP for a simple entry and exit strategy in PineScript 5, and how to fix it?

```
stopOffset = stopOffsetPercent * syminfo.mintick       
stopOffset = (close * (1 + stopOffsetPercent / 100))   // or 
shortStopPrice = high[1] - stopOffset                  // or 
shortStopPrice = high[1] * stopOffsetPercent

tp1Long = high[1] + tp1Percent * syminfo.mintick // or 
tp1Long = high[1] + (1 *  tp1Percent / 100)      // or 
tp1Long =  high[1] * tp1Percent

if ShortEntry
    strategy.entry('Short1', strategy.short, qty=1, stop=low[1])
    strategy.exit('Short Exit', from_entry='Short1', loss=shortStopPrice, profit=tp1Short, comment_loss="Short SL", comment_profit="Short TP")
```

The result is, that the SL is just 2 ticks below entry and the TP is hit immediately. First when I use tp1Percent = 5000 it is like 30 ticks away. No matter how I tweak the code, the SL and TP absolutely do not change as expected and I can't get it to where it should be. What am I missing?

Comment: profit and loss parameters is a ticks, not a price

Comment: damn, I started with V4 where I think it is but it not anymore. Many thanks! Now that explains everything

Answer (score 0):

Like Starr Lucky said, one can either use the parameter profit/loss or limit/stop in strategy.exit. The first calculate TP/SL based on distance, the other asks for a price level.